# Setting up an agent on DialogFlow Enterprise Edition?

Tags: dialogflow-es

i can’t for the life of me figure out how to create an enterprise edition agent.

this is the only documentation i’ve found about it: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/quickstart
which seems to imply that we’d need to set up agents using the command line… for them to be on Enterprise Edition.

any insight? i'd like to create an enterprise edition agent - so that it's covered by the SLA. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you click the section expansion button to the left of "If you have not created an agent, create one now."?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the below procedure will only work on Google Cloud project *not* created through Dialogflow.com.  The only way to create a enterprise edition Dialogflow agent is to first create a GCP project and then follow the procedure below.  You can't create a enterprise edition Dialogflow agent through Dialogflow.com (but you can access it on Dialogflow.com *after* creating it via the procedure described below).

1. Go to http://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/dialogflow.googleapis.com/ (create a project if you haven't already, you can only have one Dialogflow agent per cloud project) and enable the Dialogflow API
   [image]
2. After the API has been enabled click on `Dialogflow Agent` in the left column
   [image]
3. Specify the name of your agent and other properties such as language and time zone, and then click `Create`

[image]

This is documented here (you need to click on the ▼ to see the documentation): https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/quickstart#create-an-agent

Comment: I see a different navigation than you've screenshotted there. I think the issue may be that I've created the agent first through DialogFlow and then am going into GCP to edit it. Whereas, you're creating project first - and then editing DialogFlow API settings... all through GCP, before heading over to DF to edit the agent. Will give that a try.

Comment: Just edited the answer to indicate that this only works with GCP projects not created through Dialogflow.com